# Composer not working after a clean install on centos 5

Tags: php, composer-php, drush

We've been working with our hoster to install `composer` on a `centos 5` with `php 5.3.9`, and though we get no installation errors, running composer with any command always gives us the following:

```
-bash-3.2$ composer help install

??+?-bash-3.2$
```

always this funny `??+?` response.

This also happen when I download a composer.phar manually, and if I run `composer.phar` over `php`. Always the same issue. The provider technicians tried to install it with admin privileges and they also get this error. any ideas?

Comment: Check your php.ini for an `error_log` directive. Check that location for error messages?

Comment: You probably shouldn't run Composer on the production server. Here are some details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721495/how-to-deploy-correctly-when-using-composers-develop-production-switch/21722205#21722205

Comment: We need to run composer once to install drush 7

Comment: I ran composer using php -c  with a custom php.ini where I turned error logging on and the log path to an own file, but I get no logged errors. I set `log_errors = On` and `error_log = path_to_file`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by running:

`curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check`

It gave me some php.ini settings I needed.

Then I ran composer using:

`php -c pathToPhp.ini pathToComposer.phar`