# Composer & Linux production server - autoload not working

Tags: php, linux, apache, composer-php

I have already tried searching for this question and seen a couple of answers, but no luck...

I have composer installed with Slim Framework v3.

I am using autoload for my files using PSR-4 in the composer.json file like this:

```
"autoload": {
 "psr-4": {
   "App\\": "App"
 }
}
```

And this is my folder structure:

[image]

I am running it on a localhost Mac OS X El-Capitan using Apache 2.4 and everything works like magic.
But when I upload it to my Production Linux server (also with Apache 2.4), the autoload seems to be extremely confused and I am getting errors like these:

> Warning: include(/home/friendsapp/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Middleware/AuthMiddleware.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/friendsapp/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 412
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/friendsapp/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Middleware/AuthMiddleware.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/friendsapp/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 412
>
> Fatal error: Class 'App\Middleware\AuthMiddleware' not found in /home/friendsapp/public_html/public/index.php on line 5

I have namespaced my classes exactly according to my folder structure.

```
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

use \App\Middleware\Middleware;

use \App\Share\ErrorCode;
use \App\Models\ResultMessage;

use \App\Mappers\AccessTokenMapper;

class AuthMiddleware extends Middleware {
```

Any help would be most appreciated! :)

Comment: Did you run `composer install` on your server?

Comment: Or `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Aren't I supposed to not do this on the server? (at least that's what I understood from reading some comments about this issue)

Comment: I don't see where in your config its occurring, but you appear to have a difference in upper/lower case in your directory naming.  OSX is non-case-sensitive when resolving files, while linux is case sensitive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the path in the errors `/app/Middleware/AuthMiddleware.php`

It appears the issue is caused by a namespace conflict of `App\\`  being pointed to `/app` in your production environment as opposed to your PSR-4 declaration pointing to `/App`.

To avoid conflicts and map all of the namespaces of a specified directory you can use the autoload `classmap` or config `optimize-autoloader` (optional) options in `composer.json` in order to define the physical path of all the files and objects in the specified directories for composer to load. Additionally with the PSR-4 declaration, any files not found in the classmap paths will be attempted to be loaded from the `App` namespace path declaration(s). For example when using the `exclude-from-classmap` option.

```
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "App/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "App/",
    ],
}
```

After making the change in your `composer.json`, be sure to run `php composer.phar update --lock` in your development environment.

Then after uploading the `composer.lock` and `composer.json` files to your production environment, run `php composer.phar install --no-dev -o` or `php composer.phar dump-autoload --no-dev -o` from the production environment.

The `-o` option will force the `optimize-autoloader` classmapping to run and `--no-dev` will prevent the development packages (`require-dev`) from being installed. Using `optimize-autoloader` is recommended for production environments.

---

As a general practice, anytime you deploy your development changes to your production environment you need to run `php composer.phar install --no-dev -o` See [How to deploy correctly when using Composer's develop / production switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21921309/1144627). This way the changes applied from your development environment using `php composer.phar update` are installed in your production environment correctly.

Comment: That is actually.. a great answer, solved my problem! I logged in via SSH and ran "php composer.phar dump-autoload -o" and everything seems to work fine. Also thanks for the general practices, I will definitely adopt them.

Comment: Keep in mind composer.phar will automatically run in `--dev` mode, so unless you need the `require-dev` dependencies in your production environment *(such as phpunit, phpspec, behat, and codesniffer, etc)*, you would benefit from adding the `--no-dev` switch to avoid installing those dependencies (and otherwise possibly open yourself to potential vulnerabilities with development libraries).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: --no-dev -o saved me!

Comment: I add `classmap` to composer.json and run `dump-autoload -o` and it just worked.

Answer (score 1):

For my production server the following worked:

```
composer install --no-dev -o
```

**then restart php**

on serverpilot:

```
rm -rf vendor/*
composer5.6-sp install --no-dev -o
sudo service php5.6-fpm-sp restart
```

Comment: Just composer command works for me. But I have to run this command every time after creating a new class on a production server, not needed for a local server.