# Symfony 4 start session

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

New to symfony, I am trying to start my first session

here is my entire code situated under `public/php/session.php`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

$session = new Session();
$session->start();
```

I am getting error `Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session' not found`

phpstorm gives no error, do I need to install a module ? I tried `composer require session` but that does not work

I also tried the symfony doc method with `handler_id: ~` in `config/packages/framework.yaml`

with this method, no error message but no session cookie either

and here is my controller:

```
class HomeController extends AbstractController {

 // start session

  public function index(SessionInterface $session) {
   $session->set('foo', 'bar');
   $session->get('foo');
  }

  /**
  * @Route("/", name="home")
  */

  public function homepage(){
   return $this->render('home.html.twig');
  }

 }
```

Comment: Try using `php composer.phar dump-autoload -o`, see my answer on [Composer & Linux production server - autoload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39212457/1144627) Typically you would want to make a service in `/src` that you pass to your controller, as opposed to putting into your `/public` path.

Comment: trying the command from my website folder I get `Could not open input file: composer.phar`

Comment: Curious as to how you are calling `public/php/session.php`, don't think the `composer dump-autoload -o` trick will work unless you are loading it from within the controller, since `session.php` does not include the autoloader to benefit from the `-o` flag.

Comment: Well, Im back to the official method now(as described in the question); no error but not getting any session cookie

Comment: Your index method is not returning any response so no cookie will be sent back.

Comment: @Cerad but the symfony doc does not mention returning anything ? I tried `return $session` and `return $this->session` without any luck

Comment: It is basic http protocol.  Consider ditching Symfony for the moment and write a few basic examples maybe following the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).  Once you get a basic idea of how servers and browsers and cookies and sessions interact then it will become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Robert, since your code is within `public/php` it is not aware of the autoloader, which tells PHP where files are located in relation to their namespaces (PSR-0 or PSR-4).

I believe the confusion is that your `public index function` does not automatically start the session, as it is not called by Symfony unless you navigate to the `index()` function and must return a `Response`. Try passing the session to your `homepage` method arguments and navigating to it in the browser.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class HomeController extends AbstractController 
{

  /**
   * @Route("/", name="home")
   */
  public function homepage(SessionInterface $session)
  {
    $session->set('foo', 'bar');

    return $this->render('home.html.twig');
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use whole symfony framework it starts the sessions are automatically started whenever you read, write or even check for the existence of data in the session. You don't need to do that manually.

What you need to do is to define an adapter that you'll use or leave it to php configruation in

config/packages/framework.yaml

```
framework:
+     session:
+         # The native PHP session handler will be used
+         handler_id: ~
```

and then in your services, controlers just get session service

with SF4 and auto wiring enabled, in controller action

```
public function index(SessionInterface $session)
{
       $session->set('foo', 'bar');
       $session->get('foo');
}
```

that's all. See more in https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#session-intro

---

Your code is not within the framework and it won't work because there's no autoloader which would load the component from composer, it'd work if you included vendor/autoload.php but don't go that way.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I tried that too. I put it inside my home controller; The website loads but I have no session cookie in my browser ?? The symfony doc says the session should be created with the `set`?  I'll update my question

Comment: check your PHP session configuraiton then f.e in php.ini because when you set handler as ~ then symfony just uses native session configration from php

Comment: I have no php.ini in my app anywhere. if I just put `session_start()` the simple php way it works just fine

Comment: if so then put what I gave you in the config and clear cache it should work. Make sure you don't start session on your own