# Laravel git deployment from local to live server:composer automation

Tags: php, git, laravel-5, composer-php

I just setup gitdeployment to my production server from my local machine [following this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps)

Now  i am going to deploy a laravel project but i've few doubts.

1.In my laravel `git` repo `vendors` folders are excluded from the git so when i deploy the project with git to live server it doesn't worked because `vendor` folder is missing.

One solution to solve this problem is add `vendor` folder to the git buti don't think its a better practise.

**My solution**

After git deployment login to my live server and run the composer install command to add the vendors folder.

But its looks painful process suppose if a new package is added to my project (ie image intervention package)  i need to repeat my step.

So is there any way to automatically manage `vendors` folder in live server

Comment: why not add a `composer install` to that hook?

Comment: Read the second answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721495/how-to-deploy-correctly-when-using-composers-develop-production-switch   .

Comment: then add them to your git

Comment: its not a good idea to track `vendor` folder to `git`

Comment: according to that link it is a good idea as you keep in git a complete and controlled version of your application that works, at leas in dev