# Rails is precompile assets after deploy - Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, amazon-ec2, asset-pipeline, passenger

Sometimes my EC2 server is down.
I never figured out the reason.
But these days after some deployments actions, the server is down.

And is down after the deploy. I have a lot of assets to precompile and the deploy takes too long.

I went to the monitoring areas on EC2 dashboard and the:

- CPU usage (Instance)
- Latency (ELB)
- Network In/Out (Instance)

Is with higher values. See the prints:

[image: CPU UTILIZATION]

[image: Average Latency]

[image: Network In]

[image]

Then, I installed a gem [Capistrano Faster Assets](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-faster-assets), to avoid capistrano precompile assets that is not modified.

Works fine and the deploy (`cap production deploy`) is very faster and only the modified assets is precompiled.

But, after several minutes using the site, one page delays a lot to load and then shows the error 504.

I connect my EC2 via SSH, going to LOGs folder (`/var/log/nginx`) and run the command: `tail -f error.log`

For my surprise, the assets is precompiling in that moment.
I saw this in console:

```
App 1938 stderr: You probably don't mean to use the color value `orange' in interpolation here.
App 1938 stderr: It may end up represented as #ffa500, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
App 1938 stderr: Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "orange").
App 1938 stderr: If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + $palette'.
App 1938 stderr: 
App 1938 stderr: WARNING on line 15, column 16 of /home/ubuntu/my_app/releases/20170708194653/app/another/assets/folder/colors.scss:
App 1938 stderr: You probably don't mean to use the color value `purple' in interpolation here.
App 1938 stderr: It may end up represented as #800080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
App 1938 stderr: Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "purple").
App 1938 stderr: If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + $palette'.
App 1938 stderr: 
App 1938 stderr: WARNING on line 15, column 16 of /home/ubuntu/my_app/releases/20170708194653/app/another/assets/folder/colors.scss:
App 1938 stderr: You probably don't mean to use the color value `black' in interpolation here.
App 1938 stderr: It may end up represented as #000000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
App 1938 stderr: Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "black").
App 1938 stderr: If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + $palette'.
```

After that, I am going to the monitoring area and the values is higher!
Then I assume the precompile is exhaust the server.

But, why the precompile runs after deploy?
Below my configs:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'capistrano-faster-assets', '~> 1.0', group: :development
```

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/faster_assets'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

*other assets configs in this file is commented*

**Environment info**

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v: 4.2.3
nginx -v: nginx/1.8.0
passenger -v: 5.0.10
```

If you need more information, tell me on the comments.

#### Edit 1

I just sent some modifications to the server via capistrano.
No modification in assets and the `cap production deploy` ignored the `rake assets precompile` task.

But I accessed the NGINX `error.log` and nothing wrong.
When I accessed the specific URL, the page not load and the *assets scss warnings* appeared on the console (in other words, *assets precompile* is running after load page). After few minutes the browser shows me the `HTTP ERROR 504`. The CPU utilization and the Avarege Latency is higher again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Prevent the `assets precompile` task runs on the server.
I posted [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998095/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-rails-to-precompile-assets-on-production) (solved) to know how to do this.
I hope the `assets precompile` task never more runs on the server.